# Website had been showing up in Google search for my popular keyword, but today it is not

Tags: google-search, keywords

One of my websites is listed in the Google index (1st page 4th position till yesterday) for the keyword "Mobile app development company".

Today I can't see my website in the first three pages of results (30 results) for the same keyword.  What may have happened? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Can you supply the URL for your website?

Comment: www.doodleblue.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.

Site is down.   (And you're using a 200 status code instead of 503.)

Check that no "maintenance mode" has been enabled and check the server logs for any errors.

--

You can check the response headers using a sniffer such as https://redbot.org/ or with "inspect element" in your browser.

The free encyclopedia has an article on [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).  The status code is what tells the client (crawler/browser) if the request was successful or unsuccessful or if the client has to do something special (like going to a different URL instead).

Comment: How to check that?